# (PHP) Put form data into text file

Tags: php, forms

I'm a trying to make a way to store multiple links into a text file by subitting the data in my `<form>` tags into a file process.php, except the form data isn't being submitted. Afterwards the links should be clickable and deletable.

Right now I have this in my index.php:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post"> 
Name:<input type="text" name="name">
link:<input type="text" name="link">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

This is what process.php looks like right now

```
print "Website:". $name;
print "link:". $link;
```

Right now, when I enter something and submit it process.php doesn't show the data, only Website: and link: from the `print`.

I also can't figure out where to put an `<a href="">` tag inside the PHP so the link becomes clickable...

I started learning PHP yesterday, help would be appreciated a lot!

Comment: I think you should gather some basic knowledge about PHP and HTML before trying to POST data.

Comment: Right now you code is even invalid, you missed a `"` after `process.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obtain the values by `$_POST['name']` and not `$name`.

Furthermore I'm not aware if you know you should write PHP code between `<?php` and `?>`

This code however looks as it is hacked together from some how-to's. Not that this is wrong, but it requires that you at least have a basic notion of PHP. I recommend you to first look at some basic PHP before solving problems in such hacky style.

As a solution: `index.php` might look like:

```
<html><body><form action="process.php" method="post"> 
Name:<input type="text" name="name">
link:<input type="text" name="link">
<input type="submit">
</form></body></html>
```

As you can see there is no PHP involved.

and `process.php`:

```
<html><body>
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$link = $_POST['link'];
echo "<a href=\"$link\">Website $name</a>";
?>
</body></html>
```

Comment: You missed a quote around process.php

Comment: You are right, I have indeed used some code from how-to's after reading about PHP. Looking at your code right now and I understand it better, also got it working, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

change some thing like this

```
echo "Website:". $_POST['name'];
echo "link:". $_POST['link'];
```

for linking you can do something like this

```
echo "<a href=".$_POST['link'].">".$_POST['link']."</a>" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

index.php:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post"> 
Name:<input type="text" name="name">
link:<input type="text" name="link">
<input name="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

process.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  if(isset($_POST['name']))
  {
    echo "Website:<a href='#'>". $_POST['name']."</a>";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Website: No input for website";
  }
  if(isset($_POST['link']))
  {
    echo "link:<a href='#'>". $_POST['link']."</a>"; 
  }
  else
  {
     echo "Website: No input for link";
  }
}
```